# wkhtmltopdf error when I give print command

Tags: odoo, wkhtmltopdf

I have installed ODOO on google cloud and it is working fine.

But when i give print command then it gives error:

```
Unable to find Wkhtmltopdf on this system. The report will be shown in html
```

Then I installed **wkhtmltopdf** on my cloud machine (linux 16).
After after installation I check:

```
wkhtmltopdf --version
```

And it checked that wkhtmltopdf is installed.

But still the same error when I give print Command.

Comment: I’ve just [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still need to provide additional information; for instance, what is your "print command"?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have added the path where wkhtmltopdf is stored in the Odoo Service file. For instance:

```
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/lib
```

Remember that you should restart the service to get the updated path.

Make sure you have installed a well tested wkhtmltopdf library for Odoo such as this version: [0.12.1.3](https://builds.wkhtmltopdf.org/0.12.1.3/)